# Google Tag Manager API Python Set overrideGaSettings = false at Tag creation

Tags: python, google-api, google-tag-manager, google-api-python-client

I am attempting to automate GTM setup using the API and Python. However, I want to set overrideGaSettings to false when I create the UA tag and I can't seem to get it to work. I searched the api doc site for overrideGaSettings and got zero hits which I find strange.

This code works but sets overrideGaSettings = true

```
def CreateGATag(service, workspace):

  GA_tag = {
      'name': 'Google Analytics',
      'type': 'ua',
      'parameter': [
          {
            'type': 'template',
            'key': 'trackingId',            
            'value': '{{Google Analytics Settings}}'
          }
        ]
      }

  return service.accounts().containers().workspaces().tags().create(parent=workspace['path'],body=GA_tag).execute()
```

This codes gives me an invalid argument error.

```
def CreateGATag(service, workspace):

  GA_tag = {
      'name': 'Google Analytics',
      'type': 'ua',
      'parameter': [
          {
            "type": "boolean",
            "key": "overrideGaSettings",
            "value": "false"
            },
          {
            'type': 'template',
            'key': 'trackingId',            
            'value': '{{Google Analytics Settings}}'
          }
        ]
      }

  return service.accounts().containers().workspaces().tags().create(parent=workspace['path'],body=GA_tag).execute()
```

This code does set overrideGaSettings = false at tag creation without any problem.

```
def CreateGAformSubmitTag(service, workspace):

  GAformSubmittag =   {
   "name": "Universal Analytics - formSubmit",
   "type": "ua",
   "parameter": [
    {
     "type": "boolean",
     "key": "nonInteraction",
     "value": "true"
    },
    {
     "type": "boolean",
     "key": "overrideGaSettings",
     "value": "false"
    },
    {
     "type": "template",
     "key": "eventCategory",
     "value": "click"
    },
    {
     "type": "template",
     "key": "trackType",
     "value": "TRACK_EVENT"
    },
    {
     "type": "template",
     "key": "gaSettings",
     "value": "{{Google Analytics Settings}}"
    },
    {
     "type": "template",
     "key": "eventAction",
     "value": "formSubmit"
    }
   ],
   "tagFiringOption": "oncePerEvent"
  }


  return service.accounts().containers().workspaces().tags().create(
      parent=workspace['path'],
      body=GAformSubmittag).execute()
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I figured this out just a few minutes after I posted the question which seems to always happen to me.

The problem was I was setting the "trackingId" and if you do that "overrideGaSettings" must be set to true. However, if you use "gaSettings" instead of "trackingId" you can set "overrideGaSettings" to false without any problems.

Below is the working code.

```
def CreateGATag(service, workspace):
  GA_tag = {
      'name': 'Google Analytics',
      'type': 'ua',
      'parameter': [
        {
          "type": "boolean",
          "key": "overrideGaSettings",
          "value": "false"
          },
          {
            'type': 'template',
            'key': 'gaSettings',            
            'value': '{{Google Analytics Settings}}'
          }
        ]
      }

  return service.accounts().containers().workspaces().tags().create(parent=workspace['path'],body=GA_tag).execute()
```